# Use categories for default FileManager

Tags: file-manager

Is it possible in ExpressionEngine 2.x to manage your uploaded files and images with categories? So when een customer add a new image in the default FileManager, they can select one categorie (like Products, News etc).

And when you want to select a uploaded image in the default FileManager to place in a wysiwyg editor, you want to see those categories at the left side in the default FileManager. Like this:

Images
- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 2.1
Files
- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 2.1

Is their a way to do this? I know the Assets addon from Pixel and tonic...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I've re-read your question and can see that my answer doesn't really apply since you're looking to display the categories in the Files Entries list. Something like Zenbu could do this - but Zenbu only works with the entries module**

Yes, it is possible to assign categories to uploaded files in this way.

You must assign a category group to the upload directory, then when you upload the file you can edit it and apply category and other meta information.

As for accessing the categories, you can access them via the Files module using [{exp:files:entries}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/file/file_tag.html) tag pair. I'm not sure if it is possible to access the category data if using another module or add-on.

I have used this technique here http://www.haigh.co.uk/resources

Each 'resource' is just a file upload. The template uses the {exp:files:entries} tag pair to output information about each file, including the category.

The categories are used to publish files on a number of microsites managed within the same MSM installation as that site.